# HTML5 how-to read a large catalog of images for offline mobile web application

Tags: html, cordova

I am currently trying to create a mechanism to read a large catalog of products for an offline web aplication.

Currently the mechanism that I have in place is to read all the images in a loading process from a manifest file for offline caching. This has severe problems in iOS 6, only 50MB and there appears to be something broken in the support for HTML Offline in Safari for iOS6, even more so that in iOS5.

However I am faced with multiple problems. The Filesystem API is not supported in mobile browsers, and the File API does not solve my problem of reading the files. So I am currently thinking about moving my web application to a Phonegap application, but that is not without it's own issues... I am looking for a cross platform way of handling an offline image gallery.

Comment: Do you have a concrete question about phonegap? You can create a phonegap app and download all images onto the filesystem of the device. They will  be persisted and be reqachable as local files <img src="file://local/path/image1.png" />

Comment: The question is, is it possible to do this in phonegap store 30.000 images that can be read from the filesystem, or are there limitations to the amount of images I can store? Also can I read images that already exist or can I only read images that are packaged with the application? Is there a mechanism to update the image catalog, add and remove images? I looked in the docs but did not find examples of this kind of usage, so perhaps this is not the intent of phonegap apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing, to keep in mind is, that a phonegap-app is a hybrid app. Nearly everything you can perform with a native app, can also be done with phonegap.

To be more concrete in you case:

You can start with the phonegap-example.

Now you need a service (serverside), where you can get a list of images (maybe, some JSON-structure). This can be read by your phonegap app.

With the [FileTransfer object](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer) you can download files to the devices "harddrive".

Now comes the part I am not 100% sure (just 98%). If your files are stored on the device, you can simply show them, by using there `file://`-url inside an `image`-tag.

But this can be tested with a really simple app. I think you will not need more than ~50 lines of `JavaScript`, to prove my approach.

You app is limited by the platform limitations and the app-stoore conditions.

Comment: I found a tutorial, I will give it a try. Ill update this question with some code. I mainly posted this in a attempt to fish for some comments and ideas. My web app currently uses webSQL to store the data, Ill have to port my application to phonegap, and see what breaks, Ill do a POC for this. Thanks for your comments Christian.

Comment: At least share the tutorial link for others.

Comment: Can you send the tutorial link? Thanks